# Show different content based on country code top-level domain

Tags: php, redirect

I have a website which can be accessed in one of two ways:  www.foo.com and www.foo.de.  Presumably the www.foo.de visitors are from Germany, and there are about a half dozen pages on the site that will soon have German-language equivalents - e.g. the homepage (index.php), the management page (management.php), the careers page (careers.php) and so on.

What we'd like to do is serve the new German-language alternate pages if the user is visiting the site via www.foo.de.  This is a static site, nothing dynamic.

I thought maybe the way to do it (though clunky) is to

1. figure out if they're a ".de" or a ".com" visitor
2. Set a URL parameter, such as ?lang=de, if they're a ".de" visitor
3. Put a little bit of code in the header of the few relevant pages that redirect the user to the other version of the page if the parameter is "lang=de", or, I suppose, if it exists at all.

Am I making this too complicated?  To be honest, I don't care if it's an enterprise-level solution that is future proof and easily expandable.  If it's sloppy and somewhat manual, that's fine with me.

I've tried using RewriteEngine/RewriteRule in the htaccess file, but I may be over my head here.  I can't seem to get anything to detect just the top-level domain.

Help!  And thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$domain = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];

if (strtolower(substr($domain, -3, 3)) == ".de")
    die(header("Location:http://example.com"));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript as well.

```
document.URL
```

Parse the url for the country top level domain and redirect to the ?lang=de link.

Comment: Javascript executes client-side, so they would have to download the page before they would be redirected. Not to mention, some browsers don't support Javascript. I think using PHP would be more reliable, and would make more sense.

Comment: Javascript may be disabled, but what modern browser doesn't support it? 

PHP header redirect still sends a page to the client, namely the header redirect itself. Yes, the whole page won't be sent, which saves bandwidth.

Comment: Most browsers do support it, but some people access pages with their phones, many of which don't support Javascript. And some people still use older browsers. Since the post was tagged with "PHP", I assumed the page uses PHP, and since that can do it reliably as is, I didn't see a reason to add Javascript into it. Granted, it could do as you say.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make the url's map to different IP's/servers.

Comment: True, or if you don't have different IPs/servers, you could set up a virtual host so that one URL goes to one folder (document root), while a different URL goes to a different folder, both on the same server.